# find a integer in a list and return [haskell]

Tags: haskell

I am trying to find a integer within a list and return if it is true or not.

I have tried this:

```
find :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool
find n list = case list of
    [] -> False
    _:xs -> find n xs
    n:_ -> True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the gist of the recursion scheme right, but a few things are wrong in your code. First of all, as the compiler should have told you already, there are overlapping patterns in your `case` statement:

```
[] -> False -- matches an empty list
_:xs -> find n xs -- matches a list of at least one element, binding xs to its
                  -- tail; xs could be a list of elements, or the empty list []
n:_ -> True -- matches a list of at least one element, binding n to its head
```

As you can see, patterns 2 and 3 match on the same cases (lists of at least one element). Moreover, the third case will return `True` as soon as `find` encounters any element. Judging by the name of the function, I don't think that's what you want.

One other flaw in your code is that the `n` variable in the last line doesn't stand for "list with the element previously named n as its head". I can see why you would think that, but AFAIK you can't do that with anything other than literals in Haskell. Instead, what it does is that it creates another binding that shadows the already declared binding of `n`.

Now for the recursion scheme. What you want in a `find` function is two base cases:

- Return True if you found the element
- Return False if you're out of elements to look at

Therefore, your `case` statement needs to branch out into two patterns: empty list, and non-empty list. Now let's start modifying your function to fit this scheme:

```
find n list = case list of
    [] -> False  
    x:xs -> find n xs
```

We need to insert the `True` case somehow before deciding to recurse, and after checking for equality with `n`. One way to do this is nest `case` statements:

```
find n list = case list of
    [] -> False
    x:xs -> case x == n of
      True -> True
      False -> find n xs
```

This nesting of case statements works fine, but it isn't very pretty. One way to improve it is by transfering the pattern-matching right into the arguments of `find`, like in the code block below. As a bonus, I just want to show how guards make it a bit more obvious that the first decision the function makes is how to branch out:

```
find' _ [] = False
find' n (x:xs)
  | x == n = True
  | otherwise = find' n xs
```

This format is very idiomatic for primitive recursion in Haskell. One other way you'll see often is using folds. If you're learning Haskell, they're fairly basic and therefore aren't that far down the road, but here's a glimpse:

```
find'' n list = foldr (\x acc -> if x == n then True else acc) False list
-- which can be eta-reduced to:
find'' n = foldr (\x acc -> if x == n then True else acc) False
```

As @Skam pointed out, this function is already defined in the Prelude. There is also a `find` function in Data.List, but that one returns a `Maybe` value wrapping the first occurence of a value matching a given predicate:

```
>>> find odd [1,2,3]
Just 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use functions from the Prelude there exists a function

```
Prelude> :t elem
elem :: (Foldable t, Eq a) => a -> t a -> Bool
Prelude> elem 5 [1, 2, 3]
False
Prelude> elem 1 [1, 2, 3]
True
```